# запрос из БД с использованием числовых значений

Tags: android, sqlite

У Климова есть такой пункт:

Пример при использовании числовых значений, например, идентификатор первичного ключа

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("CAT", 
        new String[] {"NAME", "DESCRIPTION"}, 
        "_id = ?", 
        new String[] {Integer.toString(1)}, 
        null, null, null);
```

(более подробно http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php)

в своем приложении я проделываю нечто схожее, но работаю с числами более 128 (то есть превышающих пул интов) и при сравнении двух Integer (из базы и числа в selectionArgs) по-любому получаю неравенство. Очевидно что то я недопонял...
Просьба, растолкуйте как это будет работать с большими числами

Comment: у вас в таблице число хранится как Integer?

Comment: Да, хранится INTEGER и в selectionArgs тоже Integer

Comment: Все, разрулил. Пул тут оказался не причем. А вот что действительно не понятно, так это почему при вставке в базу данных значения типа int, оно автоматически приводится к String? То есть добавил, казалось бы, избыточное INTEGER при создании базы, после названия ячейки, и данный запрос отработал как надо!